# Multiple Xorg sessions

Tags: xorg, xrdp, framebuffer

How to start xrdp session and startx ?
I am trying to:

- Stop lightdm
- Login to to xrdp (it uses display :10)
- From tty1, startx --:1

But Xorg fails to start with the error (~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log):

```
[  2231.947] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2231.947] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2231.949] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
```

...

```
Fatal server error:
[  2231.950] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
```

/dev/fb0 exists, I don't know if it should create another one.

Entire log:

```
[  2231.901] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[  2231.907] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  2231.907] Build Operating System: Linux 4.15.0-115-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[  2231.909] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-122-generic #124-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 13:03:05 UTC 2020 x86_64
[  2231.909] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-122-generic root=/dev/mapper/xubuntu--vg-root ro quiet splash
[  2231.912] Build Date: 04 September 2020  03:34:39PM
[  2231.913] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4.6 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[  2231.914] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[  2231.916]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  2231.916] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  2231.919] (==) Log file: "/home/user/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.1.log", Time: Tue Oct 27 10:39:15 2020
[  2231.921] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  2231.921] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[  2231.921] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[  2231.921] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[  2231.921] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[  2231.921] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[  2231.921] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  2231.921] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  2231.921] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  2231.921] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  2231.921] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  2231.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[  2231.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2231.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[  2231.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2231.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[  2231.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2231.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[  2231.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2231.921] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[  2231.921]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  2231.921] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[  2231.921] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  2231.921] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[  2231.921] (II) Loader magic: 0x5566ce4c0020
[  2231.921] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  2231.921]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  2231.921]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[  2231.921]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  2231.921]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  2231.922] (++) using VT number 1

[  2231.933] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[  2231.934] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  2231.935] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 1
[  2231.935] (EE) Error systemd-logind returned paused fd for drm node
[  2231.935] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:0
[  2231.945] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 80ee:beef:0000:0000 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/16777216, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  2231.945] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  2231.945] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  2231.946] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.946]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[  2231.946]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  2231.946] (==) Matched vboxvideo as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2231.946] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2231.946] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2231.946] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2231.946] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2231.946] (II) LoadModule: "vboxvideo"
[  2231.946] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vboxvideo
[  2231.946] (II) UnloadModule: "vboxvideo"
[  2231.946] (II) Unloading vboxvideo
[  2231.946] (EE) Failed to load module "vboxvideo" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2231.946] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  2231.946] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  2231.947] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.947]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[  2231.947]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2231.947]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2231.947] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2231.947] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2231.947] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.947]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[  2231.947]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2231.947]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2231.947] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2231.947] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2231.947] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.947]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[  2231.947]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2231.947]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2231.947] (==) Matched vboxvideo as autoconfigured driver 0
[  2231.947] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[  2231.947] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[  2231.947] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[  2231.947] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[  2231.947] (II) LoadModule: "vboxvideo"
[  2231.947] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vboxvideo
[  2231.947] (II) UnloadModule: "vboxvideo"
[  2231.947] (II) Unloading vboxvideo
[  2231.947] (EE) Failed to load module "vboxvideo" (module does not exist, 0)
[  2231.947] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[  2231.947] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[  2231.947] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.947]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.19.6
[  2231.947]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2231.947]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2231.947] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  2231.947] (II) Unloading modesetting
[  2231.947] (II) Failed to load module "modesetting" (already loaded, 0)
[  2231.947] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[  2231.947] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[  2231.947] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.947]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 0.4.4
[  2231.947]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2231.947]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2231.947] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[  2231.947] (II) Unloading fbdev
[  2231.947] (II) Failed to load module "fbdev" (already loaded, 0)
[  2231.947] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[  2231.947] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[  2231.947] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.947]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 2.3.4
[  2231.947]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  2231.947]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2231.947] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[  2231.947] (II) Unloading vesa
[  2231.947] (II) Failed to load module "vesa" (already loaded, 0)
[  2231.947] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[  2231.947] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[  2231.947] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[  2231.949] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[  2231.950] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[  2231.950] (II) modeset(1): using default device
[  2231.950] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[  2231.950] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[  2231.950] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[  2231.950] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  2231.950]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.0.2
[  2231.950]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[  2231.950] (**) FBDEV(2): claimed PCI slot 0@0:2:0
[  2231.950] (II) FBDEV(2): using default device
[  2231.950] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
[  2231.950] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
[  2231.950] (EE) Screen 0 deleted because of no matching config section.
[  2231.950] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[  2231.950] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  2231.950] (EE) Cannot run in framebuffer mode. Please specify busIDs        for all framebuffer devices
[  2231.950] (EE) 
[  2231.950] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
```